# ReferenceError:Users is not defined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having an error while i was trying to deploy in firebase
with command firebase deploy.plz if any body can help.

```
 Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

 ReferenceError: Users is not defined
>at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rakib\Desktop\FirebasePushnotification\functions\index.js:6:57)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at C:\Users\Rakib\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:21:11
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rakib\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:75:3)
```

my node.js script

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.sendNotification = 


 functions.firestore.document
(Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}).on 
Write(event=> {

const user_id = event.params.user_id;
const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

console.log("User ID:" + user_id +" |Notification ID:" + notification_id);
return null;
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is that you forgot to put `Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}` into string quotes `"Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}"`

Comment: It looks like actually template literal. user_id and notification_id looks like variables

Comment: it looks, but it is not. At least it is missing backticks and dollar signs